# Evaluate a function whose arguments are stored in a list

Tags: r, function

I would like to evaluate a certain function `g` inside of a function `f`, but the arguments of `g` are given to `f` in a list. 
`f` and `g` are defined in this way:

```
g <- function(a,b){
  a+b
}
f <- function(x, y, l){
  # do some stuff on x and y
  z <- g(l)  # Not working
  # do some stuff on x, y and z
}
```

I would like to run `f` in this way:

```
f(xx, yy, list(a=aa, b=bb)
```

where `aa`, `bb`, `xx`, `yy` are some R objects.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `do.call` function in this way:

```
f <- function(x, y, l){
  # do some stuff on x and y
  z <- do.call(g,l)
  # do some stuff on x, y and z
}
```